# Starting a list mid-sentence

Tags: enumerate

I am trying to reconstruct the following look:

```
show that (a) Item 1
          (b) Item 2
```

I am unsure as how to do this. Any help you could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Show that \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}} (a) Item 1 \\ (b) Item 2 \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```